# Get number of blank textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, crossword

I am writing crossWord program
First, the user must enter a number "n" , and create a n * n table with TextBoxes that are in white color and blank.
After building the table, the user clicks on several houses and the house backcolor change to black.

My question is after this steps, how many TextBoxes are in the Black color, how many are white, How can I detect the maximum number of consecutive white text box without any black on them, in horizontally or vertically columns,to paste words that match to them!

[image]

In above table, form must detect that 5 is max of white consecutive textboxes in second horizontal line or in second vertical line, after user fill them must show 4 is max in first horizontal line, and go on to end...

Here is my code snippents:

```
private void CreateCrossTable()
{
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Trim());
    if (count > 10)
       count = 10;

    int x = 100, y = 100;
    const int value = 100;

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
        {
            x = value + (j * 20);
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Name = "txtbox" + i + "-" + j;
            tb.Location = new Point(x, y);
            tb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            tb.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.txtMouseDoubleClick);
            Controls.Add(tb);
        }

        y = value + (i * 20);
    }
}

private void txtMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    tb.BackColor = Color.Black;
    tb.Enabled = false;
    tb.Text = "|";
}
```

---

so , now I use LINQ to get All white textbox like this:

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> FreeItems = frm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(I => I.BackColor != Color.Black);
```

how can I get items those who are white and diffrence of X location of them not more than 20!

Comment: which layout control are you using to arrange text boxes

Comment: please add some code sample in your qustion

Comment: You can put a count inside onclick method for each box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following example

```
private void findConsecutive()
{

    var vertical = (from Control cnt in pnlCrossWord.Controls
                    where (cnt.GetType().Name.Equals("TextBox")) && (!cnt.BackColor.Equals(Color.Black))
                    orderby cnt.Top
                    select cnt.Top).Distinct().ToArray();
    var horizontal = (from Control cnt in pnlCrossWord.Controls
                    where (cnt.GetType().Name.Equals("TextBox")) && (!cnt.BackColor.Equals(Color.Black))
                    orderby cnt.Left
                      select cnt.Left).Distinct().ToArray();

    List<int> vList = new List<int>();
    int iIndex = 0;

    foreach (int top in vertical)
    {
        vList.Add(0);
        int vIndex = 0;
        int iConsecutive = 0;
        int iLastLeft = -1;
        var Item = (from Control cnt in pnlCrossWord.Controls
                    where (cnt.GetType().Name.Equals("TextBox")) && (!cnt.BackColor.Equals(Color.Black))
                    && (cnt.Top.Equals(top))
                    select (TextBox)cnt).ToArray();
        foreach (TextBox txt in Item)
        {
            if ((iLastLeft + txt.Width) < txt.Left && iLastLeft > -1)
            {
                if (iConsecutive > vList[iIndex])
                    vList[iIndex] = iConsecutive;

                iConsecutive = 0;
            }

            iConsecutive++;

            iLastLeft = txt.Left;
            vIndex++;
        }
        if (iConsecutive > vList[iIndex])
            vList[iIndex] = iConsecutive;
        iIndex++;
    }

    int MaxConsicutiveIndex = vList.IndexOf(vList.Max());           
}
```

**EDITED**
Above code will retrieve the Line Index of Maximum Consicutive White box in Horizontal Line.

Comment: I don't use LINQ technology until now, this code has many error... could u fix them and post again?

Comment: I found it, use LINQ to get All white textbox like this:

    IEnumerable<TextBox> FreeItems = frm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(I => I.BackColor != Color.Black);

how can I get items those who are white and diffrence of X location of them not more than 20?

Comment: @BaHaR take a look on my answer. I have edited and posted a sample code to find maximum consecutive white box.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a layout container that will allow you to arrange cells dynamically. A table should work.

For each cell store the x,y position in the tag property.

When the user clicks on a specific cell it will be easy to write a method that gives you a collection of cells or text boxes that are in the same row. Or if you want to find the answer after clicking a button you'll have to loop through all the rows.

This should get you in a good place to finish the rest.